# Let $A$ be a non-empty closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Show that $f$ has a maximum in $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $A$ be a non-empty closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $0 \le f(x,y) \le \frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2}$ for all $(x,y) \in A$. Show that $f$ has a maximum in $A$.

In order to show that $f$ has a maximum I need to show that $A$ is compact? $A$ is closed by the problem statement so I need to show that it's bounded? I know that $f(x,y)$ is bounded since the denominator of $\frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2}$ will tend to $0$ as $x,y$ get large. So $f(x,y) \in [0, 1]$. This doesn't tell me however anything about the boundedness of $A$. What can I do here?

Comment: The title is misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ need not be compact, so you can't use that theorem, you're right. The bound $0 \leq f(x,y) \leq 1$ also holds for all $x,y$, as you deduce.

But think of this : *after a certain radius*, you know that $f$ is really, really small because of the bound. If you stay within that radius, then you are very much within a compact set.

To use this more precisely, note that the supremum of $f$ on $A$, $L = \sup_{x \in A} f(x)$, exists and is finite (indeed, at most $1$). This is because $f$ is bounded.

We dispose off the case $L=0$, where we must have $f=0$ as a function and therefore $f$ has a maximum everywhere! Let's assume $L>0$ from now on.

Now, pick $x,y$ such that $\frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2} < \frac{L}{2}$. Then, for any such $x,y$ we have $f(x,y) < \frac L2< L$ as well.

It follows, that :
$$
\sup_{x \in A} f(x) = \sup_{x \in B} f(x)
$$

where $B = A \cap \{(x,y) : \frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2} \geq \frac L2\}$.

Now, all you need to show is that $B$ is closed and bounded (SHOWN LATER). Then, $f$ is continuous on $B$, and therefore $f$ will have a maximum on $B$. That same maximum will , because of what we wrote earlier also be a maximum on $A$. Done!

Key idea : Truncation of the domain into two parts , one which is bounded and one which is unbounded, but where you know $f$ behaves nicely. This kind of argument is commonly used and worth remembering.

---

Aim : To show that $B$ is closed and bounded.

To show that $B$ is bounded, it's enough to show that $\{(x,y) : \frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2} \geq \frac L2\}$ is bounded, since $B$ is a subset of this.

We write :
$$
\left\{(x,y) : \frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2} \geq \frac L2\right\} = \left\{(x,y) : 1+2x^2+3y^2 \leq \frac 2L\right\}
$$

Recall that $\|(x,y)\|^2 = x^2+y^2$, so we note that if $\|(x,y)\| > \sqrt{\frac{1}{L} - \frac 12}$, then :
$$
1+2x^2+3y^2 \geq 1+2x^2+2y^2 \geq 1+2\|(x,y)\|^2 > 1+ 2\left(\frac 1L - \frac 12\right) = \frac 2L
$$

which proves that $$\left\{(x,y) : \frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2} \geq \frac L2\right\} \subset \left\{(x,y) : \|(x,y)\| \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{L} - \frac 12}\right\}$$ i.e. that $\{(x,y) : \frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2} \geq \frac L2\}$ is bounded. Hence $B$ is bounded.

To show that $B$ is closed, we must use the fact that the preimage of a continuous function is closed, and that the intersection of closed sets is closed.

So, $A$ is closed. It's enough to prove that $\{(x,y) : \frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2} \geq \frac L2\}$ is closed. But then, it's clear that if $g(x,y) = \frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2}$, then $g(x,y)$ is continuous and :
$$
\left\{(x,y) : \frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2} \geq \frac L2\right\} = \left\{(x,y) : g(x,y) \in \left[\frac{L}{2} , \infty\right)\right\}
$$

is the preimage of the closed set $\left[\frac L2,\infty\right)$ under the continuous map $g$. Therefore, $A \cap \left\{(x,y) : \frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2} \geq \frac L2\right\}$ is closed i.e. $B$ is closed.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused on how did you came with the idea to construct $B$?

Comment: @Ralph I've seen the pattern before. There is the very common abstract question : suppose $f$ is a continuous function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $|f(x)| \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, then $f$ has a maximum on $\mathbb R$ even though $\mathbb R$ is not bounded. The idea is exactly what I said : after some radius, $f$ is really small, so we miss the maximum, and then whatever's left is closed and bounded and so the maximum is there, which turns out to be a maximum in $\mathbb R$. I used the same principle here. $B$ is basically $A$ minus the points where I showed a maximum can't occur.

Comment: I understand the case with $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. By looking at the limit behavior we can construct a interval $[-K, K]$ where $f$ attains the maximum, but this compactness confuses me.

Comment: @Ralph Compactness is nothing but being closed and bounded (in this case). Are you trying to understand why $B$ is compact? I did leave that out, so I can fill it in.

Comment: I'm not sure that $B$ is closed since I don't know about the closedness of boundedness of $\{(x,y) : \frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2} \geq \frac L2\}$? Also how is the supremums $\sup_{x \in A} f(x) = \sup_{x \in B} f(x)$ equal?

Comment: @Ralph I'll edit the answer. Suppose I show that $B$ is closed and bounded, would that satisfy you? You may ask for more, it is my duty to provide.

Comment: @Ralph Kindly see the edit made now, in which I prove that $B$ is closed and bounded.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the edit. Also how do we know that $f$ is in $B = A \cap \{(x,y) : \frac{1}{1+2x^2+3y^2} \geq \frac L2\}$? We know that it's in $A$, but is it neccessarily in $B$?

Comment: @Ralph The maximum of $f$ cannot be in $A \setminus B$. I proved that for all $x \in A \setminus B$ we have $f(x) < \frac L2$, where $L$ is the supremum of $f$. By definition of supremum, there definitely is a point $x \in A$ such that $f(x) > \frac{3L}{4}$, and such a point would have to be in $B$. So $B$ is non-empty and you can see that the maximum must occur in $B$, no value of $f$ outside $B$ is even above $\frac L2$, let alone come close to $L$. So the maximum is in $B$, but $B$ is in $A$, so the maximum is attained in $A$ for sure.

Comment: I have to mention one small, small case that I forgot about, but it's not really changing the argument. (Just the case $L=0$, handled it)

Comment: @Ralph Thank you very much for the acceptance, hope to serve you in the future.

Answer (score 2):

First, assume that $f(0) \neq 0$ (We'll tackle the $0$ case later). Then $f(0) = a > 0 $ Now for large enough $x,y$, we know that $f$ will take values which are less than $a$. Say that this happens whenever $||(x,y)|| > d$. Then to find the maximum of $f$, it suffices to find the maximum of $f$ restricted to the set $K = A \cap \{(x,y :|| (x,y)|| \leq d) \}$. Since $K$ is compact, we have that the maximum does in fact exist!

When $f(0) = 0$, we note that if the function in non-constant, then there is some $p$ for which $f$ takes positive value. From there we repeat the argument.

Comment: How is it that for large enough $x,y$ $f(x,y) < a$?